# Confused about ErrorMessages while debugging Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/frame168()

```
stop(); 
home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,home); 

function home(event:MouseEvent){ 
    gotoAndPlay(1,"scene1"); 
}

aboutus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,aboutus);

function aboutus(event:MouseEvent){ 
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene2"); 
}

gallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gallery); 
function gallery(event:MouseEvent){ 
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene5"); 
}

contactus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,contactus);

function contactus(event:MouseEvent){ 
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene4"); 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a frame script on Frame 168? If so, please post it.

Comment: 'code'stop();

home_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,home);
function home(event:MouseEvent){
 
gotoAndPlay(1,"scene1");
 
}

aboutus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,aboutus);
function aboutus(event:MouseEvent){
 
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene2");
 
}

gallery_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,gallery);
function gallery(event:MouseEvent){
 
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene5");
 
}

contactus_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,contactus);
function contactus(event:MouseEvent){
 
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene4");
 
}

Comment: Welcome to stack-overflow, you should edit your question to paste the code in there.  Read up on running your project in debug mode so you can see what the offending line is, generally speaking you are using a . to dereference a variable that is currently null.

Comment: Make sure all your instance names are spelled right and exist on the timeline:   home_btn, contactus_btn, gallery_btn, aboutus_btn

Comment: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/frame168()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:3]

Comment: i got this error on debug

Comment: Do all those objects you are trying to reference exist on frame 168?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks ok but we can not determine if you spelled everything correctly and if your buttons are present on the screen when you assign these actions.

One thing that looks odd is the spelling in this function

```
function home(event:MouseEvent){ 
    gotoAndPlay(1,"scene1"); 
}
```

Are you sure it is `scene1` instead of `Scene1`?
And there is no `Scene3`, is that correct?

Comment: there is no scene 3 I had deleted it...now i get another error that shows

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene2 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/aboutus()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:13]

Comment: Is Scene2 still present? Maybe you named it differently.

Comment: I never changed the names, but i get it when i press all the menu links

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene5 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/gallery()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:20]
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene4 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/contactus()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:27]

Comment: ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene Scene2 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/aboutus()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:13]
ArgumentError: Error #2108: Scene scene1 was not found.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
 at savethetiger_fla::MainTimeline/home()[savethetiger_fla.MainTimeline::frame168:6]

Comment: Don't paste error messages in comments, edit your original question.